# Issue with converting datetime to local time

Tags: r, datetime

I had issue with function as.POSIXlt that appears very mysterious for me. I have in data.frame over 100 000 datetimes but 3 of them didn't behave like they should and changed all datetimes when these 3 dates were included.

```
time=c("2008-03-30 03:07:44","2008-03-30 03:48:56","2012-03-25 03:22:20")    
d=as.POSIXlt(time)    
d    
## [1] "2008-03-30" "2008-03-30" "2012-03-25"
```

but it should be:

```
## [1] "2008-03-30 03:07:44" "2008-03-30 03:48:56" "2012-03-25 03:22:20"
```

Changing minutes and seconds of these dates didn't force this function to work in right way but changing hours, days, months and years then it works fine. So the problem occurs only in combination of these certain dates and hours.
Any idea what could be the cause of such rather mysterious problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behavior. I got `[1] "2008-03-30 03:07:44 CEST" "2008-03-30 03:48:56 CEST" "2012-03-25 03:22:20 CEST"`

Comment: It may occur only in my computer and the version of R i have installed:) In my computer this function doesn't add system timezones to the time.

Comment: Date/time behavior is tied the the functions available in the OS you are running. Please be clear about what OS and R version you are running, and It might be useful to say which timezone your computer is set to.

Comment: OS Win 7 32bit and R 3.0.3. Timezone is UTC +02:00. This behaviour has occured with previous R versions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of the switch from Standard Time to Daylight Saving Time. Based on your timezone (GMT+2), the switch probably took place on March 30, 2008 between 3:00 and 4:00 AM, and likewise on March 25, 2012. So anything between 3:00 and 4:00 AM never existed. R thinks it's not possible for those timestamps to exist, and defaults to the day.

I think you can get around this by setting the timezone in your POSIXlt call.

Comment: That's reasonable answer for this because switching time takes place in the last Sunday of March and these two coincide. Thanks!